# How to display text using Tkinter.Text at a random place on screen

Tags: python, tkinter

Using python Tkinter, I want to place text at random locations upon the clicking of a key on mouse. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *  
import sys
from random import randint

root = Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = 10
y = 10

def key(event):
    if event.char == 'c':
        xloc = randint(0, 100)
        yloc = randint(0, 100)
        T.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (0, 0))
        T.insert('%d.%d' % (xloc, yloc), 'something')

    if event.char == 'q':
        sys.exit()

frame = Frame(root, width=screen_width, height=screen_height)  
frame.bind("<Key>", key)  
frame.focus_set()
frame.pack()

T = Text(frame, height=screen_height, width=screen_width, bg="white", fg="blue")
T.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (0, 0))
T.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

After the window pops up, pressing 'c' causes the text to be inserted after the previous text, and not at a random location as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that and see

Comment: Tried that. Added about 3000 spaces, and tried placing the text on locations within the screen resolution. It somehow seems to fail, and text is placed after 3000 spaces. Used mark_insert() to set the cursor to 0, 0 after inserting all spaces, and before placing random text. Updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a canvas. This is very similar to your current implementation.

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    print "pressed", repr(event.char)

    if event.char == 'c':
        xloc = randint(0, 100)
        yloc = randint(0, 100)
        canvas.create_text(xloc, yloc, text='something')

canvas = Canvas(width=100, height=100, bg='white')
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind("<Key>", key)
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No problem!. On Stack Overflow the very best way to say thanks is to upvote any questions or answers you find useful. And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer. See the Help Center for guidelines.

Comment: Sure. But I have less than required points to upvote. I have marked your answer as accepted answer though

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend something like this

```
    from tkinter import *
    import random

    Text(text="put your text here".grid(row=random.randrange(0,9),column=random.randrange(0,9),columnspan=2)
```

This code simply places the text widget randomly in an 10*10 window. It should be easy enough to bind to a mouse click.